# Run Function Without Specifying Parameters in Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have some code:

```
def __petric(terms):
    while len(terms) > 1:
        z = []
        for i in terms[0]:
            for j in terms[1]:
                z.append(list(set(i+j)))
        del terms[0]
        del terms[0]
        z.sort(__sortByLen)
        __simplify(z)
        terms.insert(0, z)
    return terms
```

the `z.sort` line is calling a function, which has 2 parameters.

In Python 2, this runs and gives the expected result.

But in Python 3, this gives an error:

```
'TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function'
```

My __sortByLen function

```
def __sortByLen(x,y):
    if len(x) > len(y):
        return 1
    elif len(x) < len(y):
        return -1
    else:
        return 0
```

and a different function, same concept

```
def __sortByCost(x,y):
    cx=__getCost(x) #cost of the first
    cy=__getCost(y) #cost of the second
    if cx > cy:
        return 1
    elif cx < cy:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0
```

When i changed it to `z.sort(key=__sortByLen)` I got another error

```
TypeError: __sortByLen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: What are the unknown functions? You don't show their definitions, nor the full traceback for the error.

Comment: Note: use 4 spaces for indentation, and do *not* use a double underscore starting a variable or function name; those are reserved for Python's magic methods and such.

Comment: @Evert fixed, and I'll change the name of the function, thanks for the info

Comment: Side-note: If `terms` is a `list`, deleting the first elements one at a time is incurring massive copy overhead, as is inserting one element in the front. If possible, you might want to switch to a `collections.deque`, or `.reverse()` the input list and pop/append to the right side (which is cheap) indexing to `-1` and `-2` instead of `0` and `1`. Or if you like it the way it is, at least limited to one massive copy per loop, not three, by replacing both `del`s and the `insert` with: `terms[:2] = [z]` which deletes the first two elements, replacing them with the single value `z` in one op.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the insight @ShadowRanger

Comment: @Evert: Only using both leading and trailing double underscores is reserved for magic methods. Leading underscores is completely different; for methods, it provides interpreter support for private attributes and methods (by seamlessly name mangling). You're _supposed_ to use dunder prefixed (but not suffixed) names when you want private methods/attributes, and they never conflict with other names in an inheritance hierarchy because of the mangling; the exact opposite of being reserved. So `__sortbylen__` would be bad, `__sortbylen` is pointless if not on a class/instance, but not reserved.

Comment: @ShadowRanger True, I simplified it because I don't 100% know the underlying mechanics. But I'd refrain from anything starting with a *double* underscore and just use a single underscore if I want something to be private. Functions or variables written this way could be considered private to their module.

Comment: @Evert: The general rule is that module private stuff gets a single underscore (or if you use `__all__` to list exports, just don't include it in `__all__`). But for methods/attributes of a class, you use a single underscore to indicate protected (shouldn't be used by outside libs), and a double underscore to indicate private (even subclasses shouldn't be messing with it). This is covered explicitly in the official Python style guide, [PEP8, under "Designing for inheritance" and "Public and internal interfaces"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#designing-for-inheritance).

Answer (score 3):

Python 3 only handles `key` functions, not `cmp` functions. And in this case (like many cases), this makes it much simpler. You want to sort by length, so sort using a `key` of `len` directly (and as the error notes, it must be passed by keyword, not positionally):

```
z.sort(key=len)
```

That does a one-time precompute of all the lengths in `z`, computing each `len` just once (a total of `n` `len` calls); it then sorts `z` using those lengths. The old `cmp` approach would have been computing *each* `len` approximately `log2(n)` times, for `n * log2(n)` total `len` calls (actually, up to twice that, since you weren't saving the `len` in your `cmp` function).

So with 1024 elements, the `key` based approach calls `len` exactly 1024 times, no more, no less; the `cmp` based approach you attempted could have ended up performing up to 20x more calls to `len` (in practice, a little lower, roughly 8000-18,000 calls, with an absolute minimum 2046 times if the data is already sorted thanks to [TimSort galloping mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), but still double the `key` number because you'd need 1023 `cmp` calls, each of which computes two `len`s).

And if the result of the `key` function is a Python built-in (your `key` functions return `int`, so this is the case here) and you're using the Python reference interpreter, then the savings are even greater; sorting runs faster when it doesn't need to execute Python byte code during the sort. When using `key`s that return built-ins, after the pre-sort `key` computation, no byte code is executed during the actual sorting, and so all the work is done at the C layer and runs even faster than the strict algorithmic analysis would indicate. With `cmp`, a custom `cmp` function is almost always written in Python, so every comparison involves calling back into the bytecode interpreter, slowing things down.

Comment: Ok i see how that works.
So if i had a def that sorts by cost (This is Quine McCluskey Simplification)

def __sortByCost(x,y):
 cx=__getCost(x) #cost of the first
 cy=__getCost(y) #cost of the second
 if cx > cy:
  return 1
 elif cx < cy:
  return -1
 else:
  return 0

This is also by len correct?

Comment: @AbhishekPatel: Well, that comparator is comparing by the result of a call to `__getcost`, so you'd do `someseq.sort(key=__getcost)`. And again, it would save a whole lot of calls to `__getcost` by computing once up front, then sorting based on the cached value. It's why `cmp` was removed in Py3; `key` based sorting is almost always simpler and faster; it's giving you the [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) for free, no need to decorate, sort, and undecorate manually.

Comment: you mean `O(n * log(n))`, not `log(n)` times.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Nope, meant `log(n)`; I was referring to how many times the `len` was checked for _each_ element, not the total number of `len` checks. It's a total of `O(n log n)` `len` checks, but any given element is only `log n`. I will edit to make that a little more clear by comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Change `z.sort(__sortByLen)` to `z.sort(key=__sortByLen)`

Though you should also be sure that `__sortByLen` has the right behavior for a key function and not a cmp function (which was used by python2)

Comment: This got rid of the error, but it added another one "TypeError: __sortByLen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'"